# indexOf error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, indexof

I have an ArrayList with the values:

```
Lista
Lista2
Lista 3
```

when i use.

pCols.indexOf("Lista")) is OK

pCols.indexOf("Lista2")) is OK

pCols.indexOf("Lista 3")) ERROR java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception

Comment: The exception does not come from this piece of code. My guess : somewhere in your code, your item is not found. In this case, `indexOf()` returns `-1` and you end up searching an item at index -1 of your list.

Comment: `List.indexOf` doesn't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: my bad, the "Lista 3" has a space in the last char "Lista 3 ", sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, `the "Lista 3" has a space in the last char "Lista 3 "`, the cause is clear:

In this case, `List.indexOf` will return **-1**. Which is not in the range of the valid indices for an array, which is **0, ..., n-1** - being n the length of your array.

For your reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

The solution is obvious:

```
pCols.indexOf("Lista 3 ".trim()))
```

`trim()` will remove the unwanted trailing spaces.
For your reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()